# Git push, post commit-comment to wall of facebookgroup?

Tags: facebook, git, bitbucket

I guess this is a pretty rare question, but it would be pretty cool if there was someway of doing this. My company has a private facebook group for all the employees and I would like if all the pushes i do on my repo i have on bitbucket.org would also show up on that facebook group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitbucket doesn't have facebook integration yet. So you can either write your own script, host it somewhere and use `POST` service or write python broker for facebook and submit it to bitbucket support: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Writing+Brokers+for+bitbucket

It is likely they could accept it, as long as they already have twitter integration

Comment: Thanks for de guidance! Ill look into it, do you know if github has this natively?

Comment: @MrAzulay: nope, there is nothing looks like "facebook" in github's hooks list

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy way to make it post to Twitter: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Setting+Up+the+Bitbucket+Twitter+Service

I used to have an app in facebook that retranslates my twitter onto my wall. Don't know if this can be done with a group.